# Pandas: how to apply function that accepts array to column?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a function that iterates over an array of column items. I can not make it work on a per-item basis because it needs to iterate over all items linearly having some `with` context. SO how to do something like this:

```
df['newColumn'] = fun(df['oldColumn'])
```

How to do such thing in pandas?

Comment: What is the function output? (a list? or a single value?)

Comment: python array like `result=[]`

Comment: Have you tried `df['newColumn'] = pd.Series(fun(df['oldColumn']), index = df.index)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output is array-like with the same length as df, you can try:

```
df['newColumn'] = pd.Series(fun(df['oldColumn']), index = df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Either make a new function `fun2()` that has the same functionality as `fun()` but only for a single item and do

`df['newColumn'] = df['oldColumn'].apply(lambda x: fun2(x))`

which will apply `fun2()` to each item in the column, or cast `df['oldColumn']` to a list by calling `df['oldColumn'].tolist()`